# Python Behave + non-ascii steps on Windows

Tags: python, windows, unicode, python-behave

Python BDD framework Behave has the following code in its `runner.py`

```
with open(filename) as f:
    # -- FIX issue #80: exec(f.read(), globals, locals)
    # try:
    filename2 = os.path.relpath(filename, os.getcwd())
    code = compile(f.read(), filename2, 'exec')
```

As you can see, no charset is provided to `open`. According to its documentation, `locale.getpreferredencoding` is used for such cases.

But on Windows this function *always* return one-byte charset (so called "charset for non-unicode programs"). It is Windows-1252 for latin, Windows-1251 for Cyrillic etc.

So,UTF-8 py file is always broken.

My question is how can I use non-ascii step definitions with Behave on Windows if want to stay out of 1-byte charset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug there is that the code does not take care to open the file in *binary mode*, which would bypass any issues with local encodings.

And it seems that python-behave devs [have already fixed this issue](http://github.com/behave/behave/commit/3541025c87f30d7a3ee362a07d2e4f183e7aca5f), so one solution to your problem would be to update to the latest git version. But if you can't do that, it should be easy enough to monkey-patch the runner.py module with the current git version of the `exec_file` function.